# ajax callback data [object Object] instead of text

Tags: java, ajax, jquery-callback

i want to catch the data from server as an answer and alert it. but it is alerting [object Object] instead of my answer text "very good". here is my ajax function:

```
 function ajaxsubmit(){
   $.ajax({
     url: "/update",
     type: "POST",
  }).complete(function(data) {
      alert(data);
  });
 }
```

and my serverside function is this:

```
public static Result ajaxupdate(){
    String done = "very good!";
    return ok(done);
}
```

do i have to cast the coming data with some other thing so that it prints the normal plain text?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return String. Try this..

```
public static String ajaxupdate(){
    String done = "very good!";
    return done;
}
```

Comment: i did this: 

'public static Result ajaxupdate(){
  response().setContentType("text/plain");
  return ok("very good");
 }'

but still cannot show the string

Comment: OK thats good but why don't you change the return type of method to String. see the return type in my answer or use DWR java ajax call API learn more about [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/getting-started.html)

Comment: i saw, but if i change the type to String, i will get another problem in routes, saying that "cannot handle String" or something like this. but what i have done now must be okay, because i am returning plain text now, right?

Comment: it should work now. yes ajaxfunction is okay as it is giving you alert with the object.

Comment: I suggest you to use DWR as it is easy to use and easy to handle custom return types.

Comment: oh yeah? then i will take a look. actually, i was trying not to install extra things as i have to give this app to my prof, he should be able to run the app without installing any other things..

Comment: you dont need to install anything for DWR, just need to import the JAR into your project will run perfect anywhere.

Comment: oh okay, then cool. let me study this then. i will let you know here in a while